# cryptography and use of python programming language

Tags: cryptanalysis, implementation

why is it recommended to write cryptography programs ,for example crypt-analysis projects with python programming language?
what is the advantages of python? why not use c or any other language?

Comment: I have never heard this

Comment: There are some nice libraries for python, such as SAGE or Charm and it's a high level language so it's good for producing working programs quickly. On the other hand it sucks for high performance and side channel resistant crypto implementations. So it's nice for research but not for production crypto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no such recommendation. Python is quiet useful for quick prototyping, but is generally very slow. Too slow to do any expensive computations. However, you can, for instance, write you core analysis functions in c and then use them in your python analysis tools. This is actually a quiet common method of going about things.